# Alternative to iframe for embedding active external content

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, coldfusion

Pardon me if this has been answered, but I couldn’t find an answer for our specific application.

Is there a good alternative to using an iframe for embedding external content in a site?

Essentially we want to be able to give a site developer some simple code to place on a page to include our mapping widget such as this iframe example:

```
 <iframe src=“https://externaldomain.com/map/index.cfm?mapID=123”> </iframe>
```

We are using bootstrap 3 for the mapping page to be embedded and also want to maximize bootstrap responsive functionality for desktop and mobile devices on the calling sites page.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered searching for "Alternative to iFrame"?

Comment: Yes, I did.  The answer you reference was initiated 4 years ago, and being new here I probably should have asked a follow-up there.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use cross-domain AJAX call, you could load the external content dynamically with AJAX. However, it is likely that you can't do a cross-domain AJAX call and then there is not really a good alternative to iFrame I'm afraid :(